Virtual Environment setup issue in Powershell
In vs code when I am trying to setup virtual environmentin powershell, it shows this message.

.venv\Scripts\activate : File C:\PYTHON\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ .venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

I used this command to activate the virtual env
.venv\Scripts\activate
Then I found a solution online for this, It said to use the command
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
It worked, but I am forced to use this command every time when I try to activate Virtual Environment.
Its like when I close the terminal and open a new one, I have to run this command.
The virtual environment is working fine on cmd, the issue is only for powershell.
PS: I tried to set the command from the windows powershell and the vscode. Also I am new to python and vscode.
Expecting to activate a virtual env in the powershell.

Did you review about_Execution_Policies?

Use -Scope CurrentUser instead of -Scope Process in order to set the execution policy persistently.

Unfortunately, PowerShell defaults to preventing execution of script files (*.ps1) in workstation editions of Windows, necessitating a change in execution policy first, such as with Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
See the linked documentation and duplicate for details (note that the question there is about a slightly different scenario, but the answers cover the basics).
